# Tagging multiple sub-folders in Subversion

Tags: svn

My repository has a directory structure like:

```
trunk/Distribute/App1
trunk/Distribute/App2
trunk/Source/App1
trunk/Source/App2
trunk/Source/Install/App1
trunk/Source/Install/App2
```

What I want to do is create a single tag that applies to all the App1 directories, such as "App1_v4". This was fairly simple when my repository was in CVS - I just created the same tag in each folder. When I converted my repository to Subversion, those tags came over as I expected them to. However, in Subversion, while I can create a tag on just a single folder (e.g. `trunk/Source/App1`), once I do that, I cannot apply the same tag to another folder (e.g. `trunk/Distribute/App1`), as I get a duplicate tag error. This tells me that to apply tags this way, it has to be done in a single operation. But I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: depends on what do you mean by tags in svn. Usually it's a just folder named `tags`, where is it located in your case?

Comment: The `tags` folder is adjacent to `trunk`, as is `branches`.

Comment: what command do you use to create a tag? if it is just `svn copy ^/trunk/Distribute/App1 ^/tags/App1_v4` then of course it doesn't work because tags/App1_v4 already exists. You'd need to look how your migration process organized the tags folder and just follow the structure. There is no technical reason stopping you from adding subfolders to an existing tag folder

Comment: Right now my tags folder is empty in my working copy. I didn't check those out of the repo because I'm afraid it will pull the entire body of code for each tag. I'm wondering if I can just check out one tag at a time, though, or maybe just the top level for all the tags. (I'm very much a Subversion newbie in case you haven't guessed. And I use TortoiseSVN for just about everything I do with it.)

Comment: you can use repo browser in turtoise svn to view remote folders without downloading them. In the explorer you can open the context menu of any folder, select TortoiseSVN -> Repo-browser and enter the url of your remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

Tags in Subversion work differently from tags in CVS (or Git, to name another popular VCS). Essentially, a tag is just another branch. By convention, it is kept below the `tags` path (as opposed to `branches`) and - also by convention - usually not changed. Just like any other branch, a tag is created using the `svn copy` command (or equivalent in TortoiseSVN). The canonical resource is the SVN Red Bean Book, see the chapter on [Tags](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.tags.html).

The thing in Subversion that comes closest to a tag in Git is the global *revision* number. Both Subversion and Git differ from CVS in that revisions, commits and tags are global to the repository rather than per-file. So, in Subversion you don't create a tag "on a folder" but on the whole repository.

Having a tag that can be changed just like a branch may seem strange at first. But keep in mind that CVS also allows retagging.

Now that we've established that a tag is a branch, we see that there's really no need to create it in one operation. You can create a tag and change it until you're satisfied with the result.

To keep the confusion to a minimum, I would recommend to create a regular branch first, change it until you like it and then create a tag from it. Using the CLI and assuming you're in a working copy on `trunk`, it would look somewhat like this:

```
svn copy ^/trunk ^/branches/App1_v4rc -m"Release candidate for App1 version 4"
svn switch ^/branches/App1_v4rc
# make your changes, e.g.
svn rm Distribute/App2 Source/App2 Source/Install/App2
svn commit -m"Everything is ready for App1 version 4"
svn copy ^/branches/App1_v4rc ^/tags/App1_v4 -m"Create App1 version 4"
```

Above example is loosely based on the [Release Branches](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.release) example.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I'm using TortoiseSVN, as I'm not that familiar with using svn from the command line. I found that what I can do to create a tag consisting of disparate directories/files is create a tag on the whole trunk, then remove the directories and files from the tag that don't belong there. It's a little more time-consuming than what I used to do in CVS (which was apply the same tag to each of multiple directories/files), but not too much.

Comment: @KevinRahe it's not really a big problem. Usually, `svn foo` is found in TortoiseSVN's context menu as *Foo*. Once you've understood the underlying principles, it doesn't matter which client you're using. And yes, you need to create a tag on the whole thing, that's how Subversion works. My answer contains another level of indirection so tags don't ever change.